# Give an isomorphism $g:V\rightarrow W$ such that ...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

I have the two following questions that I'm having trouble approaching. In what way would I find an isomorphism here?

> Define V and G:
>
> $V=\big\{x=\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^3; x_1+x_2+x_3=0\big\}$
>
> $W=\big\{x=\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^3; x_3=0\big\}$
>
> Give an isomorphism $g:V\rightarrow W$ such that $g(\begin{pmatrix}1
>  \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$
>    and $g(\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\
>  1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$.
>
> What is $g(\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix})$ for
>   $\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}\in V$?

To me it looks like there is something going on with the identity matrix, but I don't know where to start. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does "$1>$" or "$>1$" mean here?

Comment: @lulu That was a typo from when I made the text a quote. It's fixed now.

Comment: Got it.  Hint:  the two given vectors are a basis for $V$.  If you can write a general vector in $V$ as a linear combination of them, then you can read off how to evaluate $g$.

Comment: @cdignam Your question has been answered by levap. Let me add some remarks.  Note that $g$ has been already specified at two vectors namely, $(1,-1,0)^T, (1,0,-1)^T$. These two vectors form a basis for $V$.  A linear transformation (in this case the isomorpphism) is completely determined once its values are known on a set of vectors forming a basis. For a general vectors its value is obtained by using linearity. That is what has been explained in the answer by levap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $v_1 = (1,-1,0)^T$ and $v_2 = (1,0,-1)^T$. Then $v = (x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$ can be written as

$$ v = -x_2 v_1 - x_3 v_2.$$

Using the linearity of $g$, we have

$$ g \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix} = g(-x_2 v_1 - x_3 v_2) = -x_2 g(v_1) - x_3 g(v_2) = \begin{pmatrix} -x_2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -x_3 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -x_2 \\ -x_3 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$